# Library fails to compile

Tags: library, audio

I want to try out this library:
https://github.com/connornishijima/arduino-volume3

I downloaded the zip file from github, renamed it, and included it as a library in the IDE.

So run one of the examples, `A4_440HZ`
This is its code:

```
#include "Volume3.h"
#define speakerPin 9

uint16_t frequency = 440;

void setup() {
  // Nothing neeeded here!
}

void loop() {  
  for(uint16_t volume = 0; volume < 1023; volume++){
    vol.tone(speakerPin,frequency,volume);
    delay(1);
  }
  for(uint16_t volume = 1023; volume > 0; volume--){
    vol.tone(speakerPin,frequency,volume);
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

And i get this error:

```
Error Compiling
A4_440Hz.cpp.o: In function `loop':
/usr/share/arduino/A4_440Hz.ino:12: undefined reference to `vol'
/usr/share/arduino/A4_440Hz.ino:12: undefined reference to `vol'
/usr/share/arduino/A4_440Hz.ino:16: undefined reference to `vol'
/usr/share/arduino/A4_440Hz.ino:16: undefined reference to `vol'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what is to blame, or how to mitigate it.

This is the first time that an included example from a library does not play out of the box.

Comment: It compiles here. What IDE version are you running?

Comment: You could have just installed the library from the library manager in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: They are using `extern Volume vol;` in header file, but there is no definition in cpp, nor in the sketch. The `Volume vol;` will be needed in your code, I suppose

Comment: The second part of that library, the TimerOne uses the same pattern, but it has both the declaration in header file and the definition in cpp file [line 41 TimerOne.cpp](https://github.com/connornishijima/arduino-volume3/blob/5fbc498038c83cb0f771c65e1e4cb02e4bf8415b/src/TimerOne.cpp#L41)

Comment: @timemage It is 2:1.0.5. It does not have a library manager. Perhaps it is an old version? But i installed it recently. I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @user1584421 Very old and a common problem. In case you're wondering, the `2:` is not part of the IDE version. That is part of a Debian style package versioning scheme. What you're looking at is IDE version 1.0.5 from 2013. Debian and Ubuntu could do everyone a favour by removing these packages, but they don't. Unpack (optionally install) from the tarball instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a weird situation. The library declares the object
`vol`, but fails to define it. On the ancient version of the Arduino IDE
you are using, compilation fails, understandably, because `vol` has
never been defined. What is weird is that, on a more recent version
(1.8.15 on Ubuntu here), compilation succeeds.

It is worth noting that `vol` belongs to the class `Volume`, which is an
empty class. As such, it only plays the role of a namespace for the
functions `vol.tone()` and `vol.noTone()`. Strictly speaking, as `vol`
has no data (its size is zero), the compiler should never need to access
it. My guess is that the newer Arduino manages to compile this only
because it uses different optimization settings than the ancient 1.0.5.

Anyhow, you have two options:

- upgrade your installation of the Arduino IDE
- declare `Volume vol;` near the top of the sketch.

**Edit**: I did some tests and it appears that, as I suspected, this is
related to [link-time optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (LTO). Since version 1.5.7, the
Arduino IDE enables LTO, and when this is the case, the linker doesn't
complain about missing empty objects.

The library could be fixed by defining `vol` in Volume3.cpp, although
this would create a weird empty object in the BSS. Another option would
be to declare both methods as `static` within Volume3.h. This would make
the compiler know it doesn't actually need to reference the `vol` object
when one of its methods is called.

Would you submit a pull request with one of those fixes?

Comment: Thank you! I tried both! The library compiles but no sound is heard. I guess it is an old library.

Comment: Same regarding optimizer. To be clear, the code was always incorrect. It is only a question of whether the problem manifests from that.

Comment: So if i do your suggestions, will the lib work? Did you manage to make it run? BTW, the last sentence is this targeted to me?

Comment: @user1584421: It should work, although I tested only on example code with my host compiler. And yes, the last sentence was a suggestion for you.

Comment: Thank you. But inside `Volume3.cpp` i defined `Volume vol;`. I then used one of the examples.The library compiled/uploaded but nothing is heard from the speakers.